# Ruby on Rails project json issue (and more) on Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

So, I'm having a problem creating a new project. I'm trying to follow the steps to a rails tutorial, but I'm getting stuck after just the second step. I'm currently using Ruby 2.2.1p85 and Rails 4.2.1.
I typed in "rails new blog" in cmd (running as administrator) and I get the following:

```
    C:\Users\User\Documents>rails new blog
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3
 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/jso
n-1.8.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you don't have `make` installed on your system. You can download it for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm). Honestly, instead of doing that, I would highly suggest that you use Virtual Box, or install a copy of a linux distro. Working with ruby and rails on Windows can be problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried both suggestions of yours. I originally tried using VB. But, no matter, what I did, it would always run extremely slow. I downloaded make.exe and I still got the same problem. ("Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.")